# How to set nav-bar to default to open in HTML?

Tags: html

Thanks in advance! I'm very new to HTML and just built my first site. I've looked through other similar questions but have found no clear answer to this specific problem.

I'm hoping to get the navigation bar to default to open. I've tried commenting out each line of code separately and changing small things in the js but I can't seem to isolate the problem.

Here's the site right now, with the menu icon top center: https://charlottemcclintock.github.io

The HTML:

```
<!--menu start-->
<div class="menu" >
<a href="#" class="nav-icon" id="nav-show"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navwrapper">
                <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <!--<div class="logo">logo</div> -->
                        <div align="right" class="navArea"><a href="#" class="closeMenu"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button  type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                                 <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>  --></div>
                                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li class="menuItem active"><a href="#wrapper">Home</a></li>
                                        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#aboutus">About Me</a></li>
                                        <li class="menuItem"><a href="resume.html" target = "_blank" >CV</a></li>
                                        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#" target = "_blank" >Photography</a></li>
                                        <!-- <li class="menuItem"><a href="#education">Education</a></li> -->
                                        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#ourwork">Portfolio</a></li>
                                        <li class="menuItem"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                    <!-- </ul> -->
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Navbar -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--menu end-->
```

The relevant javascript:

```
$('#nav-show').click(function(x){
    x.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('noGap');
    $('.navbar-wrapper').animate({
        opacity:1
    },200);
    $('.navbar-wrapper').removeClass('default-menu');
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

$('.closeMenu').click(function(x){
    x.preventDefault();
    $('.navbar-wrapper').animate({
        opacity:0
    },50,function(){$('.navbar-wrapper').addClass('default-menu');});

    $('#nav-show').fadeIn();
});
```

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: close your `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` tag.  I also made a fiddle [Is this the way it looks?](https://jsfiddle.net/z3v706ro/4/)

Comment: I must have commented it out and missed it. Closed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and see if it works.

```
$('.wrapper').removeClass('noGap');
    $('.navbar-wrapper').animate({
        opacity:1
    },200);
    $('.navbar-wrapper').removeClass('default-menu');
    $(this).fadeOut();
$("#nav-show").hide(); // This line is edited.

$('#nav-show').click(function(x){
    x.preventDefault();
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('noGap');
    $('.navbar-wrapper').animate({
        opacity:1
    },200);
    $('.navbar-wrapper').removeClass('default-menu');
    $(this).fadeOut();
});

$('.closeMenu').click(function(x){
    x.preventDefault();
    $('.navbar-wrapper').animate({
        opacity:0
    },50,function(){$('.navbar-wrapper').addClass('default-menu');});

    $('#nav-show').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: It did! The nav-bar icon now shows up in the middle but I can fix that! Thank you!

Comment: I fixed it here. :) But if you find better way, do it. ;)